# Issue with custom layout when porting from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a custom layout with styled attributes defined in attrs.xml. In eclipse, everything was working fine.

In android studio, although this class loads correctly in the layout editor, when calling setContentView I get a class not found exception.

```
09-05 12:36:14.376  29971-30097/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-05 12:36:14.508  29971-29971/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.turboirc.tgps.v3, PID: 29971
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.turboirc.tgps.v3/com.turboirc.tgps.v3.Act_Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1959)
            at com.turboirc.tgps.v3.Act_Main.OrC(Act_Main.java:190)
            at com.turboirc.tgps.v3.Act_Main.onCreate(Act_Main.java:630)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5385)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.turboirc.tgps.v3-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.turboirc.tgps.v3-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1959)
            at com.turboirc.tgps.v3.Act_Main.OrC(Act_Main.java:190)
            at com.turboirc.tgps.v3.Act_Main.onCreate(Act_Main.java:630)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5385)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    xmlns:pl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

     >

    <com.turboirc.tgps.v3.ViewTextInformation
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        pl:py="0"
        pl:ph="30"
         />

    <com.turboirc.tgps.v3.ViewTextInformation
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        pl:py="30"
        pl:ph="15"
         />

  <com.turboirc.tgps.v3.ViewGPSCompass
        android:id="@+id/compass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        pl:py="45"
        pl:ph="50"
         />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dirtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        pl:py="95"
        pl:ph="4"
         />


</com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout>

                                                 <LinearLayout
                                                 android:layout_width="250dp"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_gravity="start">

                                                     <ListView
                                                     android:id="@+id/leftpanel"
                                                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                                                     </ListView>
                                                 </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What could be the issue?

Best Regards.

Comment: Please post the `xml` file

Comment: Done. XML file posted.

Comment: Put `xmlns:pl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in `DrawerLayout`. Try if that works. Also, there's problem in the Google Play Services. Follow this to add ads in app in Android Studio - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: If the above doesn't work, please post `PercentageLayout` code.

Comment: PercentageLayout constructor added. Putting the xmlns:pl in DrawerLayout didn't work.

I don't see why it fails. In the editor it works. In eclipse it used to work.

Comment: It's not the PercentageLayout, I changed it to ViewGroup and it still fails.

Comment: You have 2 xml namespace referring to `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. Can you try to use app instead of pl and remove `xmlns:pl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: @hoomi It's not a matter of PercentageLayout ... I changed it to ViewGroup and it still fails.

Comment: I am not saying it is depending on PercentageLayout. What I am saying is that you are defining the same name space twice with two different names "app" and "pl". So even if you change `com.turboirc.tgps.v3.PercentageLayout` to `ViewGroup` you still have `xmlns:pl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as one of the attributes

Comment: If that did not work I would suggest you try  to remove all the elements and add them one by one to see which one is causing the issue

Comment: No luck at all. It seems that the project is messed up. Now it started causing VerifyError's and NoClassFound exceptions. :(